# How to keep the same session on the client-side during the Facebook OAuth authentication process?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, csrf

Authenticating with the Facebook OAuth involves the user clicking a login link on the client/app-side (in my case it's a website) – that is, (1) making a request to the website, getting redirected to Facebook (with a website-generated state/CSRF value), and then (2) redirected back to the website (with "code" information, passing along the state/CSRF value). (See a diagram, for example, on this page – http://blog.facilelogin.com/2013/02/why-oauth-it-self-is-not-authentication.html – the first two lines in the diagram.)

During the request/redirection (1), the website is supposed to store user's CSRF value and check if it matches with the one in request (2).

The problem I'm getting is that if a user does request (1) in an Android mobile Chrome browser, the redirect to Facebook may sometimes get opened by Android Facebook app (its in-app browser; as opposed to m.facebook.com being opened by the same Chrome browser), which seems to have its own separate Chrome instance.

The Facebook app then uses its own browser to do the callback request to the website, but it has its own cookies (and a different User-Agent string), so the user lands in a different session, lacking the CSRF value, and the authentication is invalidated.

What am I doing wrong? Am I supposed to actually identify the user's session by the "state" value (no more than once)? Or is it possible to avoid the Facebook login window being opened by Facebook app? Or to force it to use the same Chrome instance the user used for browsing the website, and not use a different one?

Comment: For the reference, I cannot reproduce this anymore – Facebook app does not intercept the authentication requests anymore, whatever I'm doing. So, I assume they've fixed something on their side, and this problem does not need to be addressed anymore. (The solution I was preparing for this was to include a one-time token into the state value, and once the user returns, restore/recreate/change their session to the original one based on that token.)

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook needs authentication process again and again , but one solution is that saving data in shared preferences and after opening again check either data is exists or not

Comment: Do you mean shared preferences within the smartphone? In my case, this is a website using Facebook's OAuth to log in a Facebook user.